# Bash command to move only some files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Let's say I have the following files in my current directory:

```
1.jpg
1original.jpg
2.jpg
2original.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
```

Is there a terminal/bash/linux command that can do something like

```
if the file [an integer]original.jpg exists,
    then move [an integer].jpg and [an integer]original.jpg to another directory.
```

Executing such a command will cause 1.jpg, 1original.jpg, 2.jpg and 2original.jpg to be in their own directory.

**NOTE**
This doesn't have to be one command.  I can be a combination of simple commands.  Maybe something like copy original files to a new directory.  Then do some regular expression filter on files in the newdir to get a list of file names from old directory that still need to be copied over etc..

Comment: This is why superusers learn programming :) Good question.

Comment: Do you have to worry about the case where there might be, say, `5original.jpg` but no `5.jpg`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turning on extended glob support will allow you to write a regular-expression-like pattern. This can handle files with multi-digit integers, such as '87.jpg' and '87original.jpg'. Bash parameter expansion can then be used to strip "original" from the name of a found file to allow you to move the two related files together.

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in +([[:digit:]])original.jpg; do
    mv $f ${f/original/} otherDirectory
done
```

---

In an extended pattern, `+( x )` matches one or more of the things inside the parentheses, analogous to the regular expression `x+`. Here, `x` is any digit. Therefore, we match all files in the current directory whose name consists of 1 or more digits followed by "original.jpg".

`${f/original/}` is an example of `bash`'s pattern substitution. It removes the first occurrence of the string "original" from the value of `f`. So if `f` is the string "1original.jpg", then `${f/original/}` is the string "1.jpg".

Answer (score 3):

well, not directly, but it's an oneliner (edit: not anymore):

```
for i in [0-9].jpg; do
  orig=${i%.*}original.jpg
  [ -f $orig ] && mv $i $orig another_dir/
done
```

edit: probably I should point out my solution:

- `for i in [0-9].jpg`: execute the loop body for each jpg file with one number as filename. store whole filename in `$i`
- `orig={i%.*}original.jpg`: save in `$orig` the possible filename for the "original file"
- `[ -f $orig ]`: check via `test(1)` (the `[ ... ]` stuff) if the original file for `$i` exists. if yes, move both files to `another_dir`. this is done via `&&`: the part after it will be only executed if the test was successful.

Comment: You should format your code onto multiple lines so that it easier to read. Also, you can avoid using basename with `${i##*/}` instead.

Comment: thanks. avoiding basename and using pattern matching is a good idea, but `${i##*/}` didn't work for me. I used `${i%.*}` instead.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for any strictly numeric prefix, i.e. `234.jpg`

```
for f in *original.jpg; do
  pre=${f%original.jpg}
  if [[ -e "$pre.jpg" && "$pre" -eq "$pre" ]] 2>/dev/null; then
    mv "$f" "$pre.jpg" targetDir
  fi
done
```

`"$pre" -eq "$pre"` gives an error if not integer

EDIT:
this fails if there exist `original.jpg` and `.jpg` both.
`$pre` is then nullstring and `"$pre" -eq "$pre"` is true.

Answer (score 1):

The following would work and is easy to understand (replace `out` with the output directory, and `{1..9}` with the actual range of your numbers.

```
for x in {1..9}
do
if [ -e ${x}original.jpg ]
then
mv $x.jpg out
mv ${x}original.jpg out
fi
done
```

You can obviously also enter it as a single line.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Regex statements to find "matches" in the files names that you are looking through.  Then perform your actions on the "matches" you find.

Comment: thanks, can you show an example solution based on the file names given  above?  I learn best from seeing sample solutions

Answer (score -1):

`integer=0; while [ $integer -le 9 ] ; do if [ -e ${integer}original.jpg ] ; then mv -vi ${integer}.jpg ${integer}original.jpg lol/ ; fi ; integer=$[ $integer + 1 ] ; done`

Note that here, "lol" is the destination directory. You can change it to anything you like. Also, you can change the `9` in `while [ $integer -le 9 ]` to check integers larger than 9. Right now it starts at 0* and stops after checking 9*.

Edit: If you want to, you can replace the semicolons in my code with carriage returns and it may be easier to read. Also, you can paste the whole block into the terminal this way, even if that might not immediately be obvious.

Comment: You should consider formatting your code in a way that is easy to read and maintain.